# Missing data on inserting in AWS DynamoDB 20000 items. No error, no UnprocessedItem, no throttling

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a lambda that insert 20000 items on a dyanmo db table using **batchWrite** this is the function that insert the items

```
async function writeOnDynamoDB(items: any, ruleId: string) {
    const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    const batchWriteParams: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.BatchWriteItemInput = {
        RequestItems: {
            ["myTable"]: [],
        },
    };
    console.log('Start inserting rows')
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        let item = items[i];
        item.id = ruleId

        const putRequest: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.WriteRequest = {
            PutRequest: {
                Item: item,
            },
        };
        
        batchWriteParams.RequestItems["myTable"].push(putRequest);
        
        if (i > 0 && i % 24 === 0) {
            console.log("Insert chunck", i,)
            const result = await dynamoDB.batchWrite(batchWriteParams).promise();
            console.log('Result',result)
            batchWriteParams.RequestItems["myTable"] = [];
        }
    }
    
    if (batchWriteParams.RequestItems[CardManager.instance().getTableName()].length > 0) {
        await dynamoDB.batchWrite(batchWriteParams).promise();
    }

}
```

On 20000 items only almost 14000 are inserted. I get no error no UnprocessedItems. The write capacity on the table is set on "On demand".
Here the log of the function

```
INFO Start inserting rows
.....

INFO Insert chunck 19824

INFO Result { UnprocessedItems: {} }

INFO Insert chunck 19848

INFO Result { UnprocessedItems: {} }

INFO Insert chunck 19872

INFO Result { UnprocessedItems: {} }

INFO Insert chunck 19896

INFO Result { UnprocessedItems: {} }

INFO Insert chunck 19920

INFO Result { UnprocessedItems: {} }

INFO Insert chunck 19944

INFO Result { UnprocessedItems: {} }

INFO Insert chunck 19968

INFO Result { UnprocessedItems: {} }

INFO Insert chunck 19992

INFO Result { UnprocessedItems: {} }

INFO End inserting rows
```

Every call to batchWrite seems returning with no errors.
Before writing I check that the combination of partitionKey + sortkey is unique among the items. (they have the same partitionkey but different sortkey).
What could be?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure none of the items are duplicates?

Comment: 100% sure. The partition key is the same, but before running the function a check for duplication every sortkey inside the items

Comment: Where is your code for checking that pk+sk is unique? Also, how are you determining the actual number of items written?

Comment: I assure you they are unique I have a test array created with 20000 rows of uniquer sortkeys. If I try to insert the same pk+sk more the once I get an error. To determine the items written I query the table by partition key.

Comment: If I understand your comment about "insert the same pk+sk more the once I get an error", that will only happen if the two duplicate primary keys are in the same batch.

Comment: Yes, I also added this code to check for duplicate in all 20000 rows but nothing found:    `....
 let duplicateObjectsDetector : any = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        let item = items[i];
        if(duplicateObjectsDetector[item.sortedKey]) {
            console.log("#####sortkey already present...", item.sortedKey)
        } else{
            duplicateObjectsDetector[item.sortedKey] = true
        }
 ....`

Comment: If you haven't resolved this yet, how is writeOnDynamoDB being called? And is the execution environment AWS Lambda or something else?